# Machine Learning: How ML algorithms build classification rules

Tags: machine-learning

I am truly fascinated by algorithms learning on their own with a little help from humans and as a newbie in this field (with programming experience mainly in C/C++), seek your help to obtain the big picture before delving into specifics. I am not a researcher, but broadly want to know what is happening under the hood. A nudge in the right direction is all I need.

What I have learnt so far can be summarized as:

- There is both supervised and unsupervised learning.
- Supervised learning is typically used to solve regression and classification
- Unsupervised learning is used to solve clustering related problems
- In supervised learning, we provide training data that are labelled
- Each training data example can comprise multiple features.
- An ML algorithm reads the labelled data, possibly finds patterns and "deduces" a general rule that maps input to output (e.g. mapping between a feature vector and a label)
- If now an unlabeled feature vector was given, the algorithm uses the "deduced" rule and classifies the input into a label class.
- I also understand that there are quite a few classification algorithms like SVM, Nearest neighbor, Decision Trees etc.
- Each of these algorithms have different criteria that leads them to different "deduced" rules on basis of which, they perform classification.

So the concepts am so desirous to understand at a broad level are:

- How does an algorithm determine inter-relation ship among features?
- How does it know what features are to be considered and what could possibly be disregarded?
- What does a deduced rule physically look like?
- Is there a standard suite of rules to choose from?
- How does the algorithm arrive at such a rule?

For example, if I had a dataset as the following:

```
0 1 0 0 1 1   +
1 1 1 0 1 1   +
1 1 0 1 1 0   +
1 0 1 0 1 1   -
1 0 1 1 1 1   -
0 1 1 0 0 0   -
```

In the above example, the label is + if the second and fifth element were 1. How will an algorithm deduce this?

I shall be truly grateful for any clarification you provide.

EDIT

Based on Jan's recommendation, my question boils down to the following:

Assume x1, x2 ... xn are attributes/features. Assume h(y) is the mapping function and it exists. How does the algorithm decide that h(y) should be (x1 + x2 + x9) /5 and not h(y) = Sq Root(x1^2 + X9^3) + k

Given the size of the dataset, the possibilities are endless, isn't it?

h(y) could either be a direct classification or some value that could lead to a class subsequently.

Comment: I think this question may be too broad to attract a satisfactory answer.

Comment: You are entitled to your opinion. But the main reason why people come to these forums is because they need the spark/insight/intuition which classic literature does not provide. Satisfactory answer or not is for the OP to decide and not you!

Comment: I agree this question is too broad. Also there are several questions here, please ask only one definitely answerable question per post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your edited question: any learning algorithm (more specifically: supervised classification) algorithm *always* (either implicitly or explicitly) works with a well-defined class of *hypotheses* or mappings from examples to labels. In the case of the perceptron in my previous answer, it works with linear separators (and hence will not consider hypotheses involving square roots). A standard no-free-lunch theorem shows that an algorithm whose hypothesis space is too rich will no be able to learn (it will overfit).

Answer (score 0):

A perceptron
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron
or SVM
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine
learning algorithm would find a separating hyperplane -- which in your case, would be something like $w=(0,1,0,0,1)$ with bias $b=-1$.